# TextMate 2 Escape key: how to disable next completion and previous completion

Tags: textmate, textmate2

By default, pressing Esc in TextMate cycles through possible completions (in addition to closing dialog boxes), which can put unwanted characters in your document, especially if you are used to Esc being a safe key to hit in most text editors. (In fact, in a lot of IDEs, pressing Esc a lot is necessary to *close* auto-completion popups so the up and down arrow keys work.)

How do I disable this behavior, so in normal text editing, the Esc key does nothing, but closing dialogs still works as expected?

Comment: http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2017-February/040243.html

Comment: Please do not close this question or downvote it without saying why. I am trying to set a simple preference in the app and would like an answer. Those who did not read it saw the rambling but did not see that it is an answerable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## What works

Based on a comment from @matt I found that I can do what I need by overriding the default key binding, as mentioned here, https://manual.macromates.com/en/key_bindings.html :

> In addition TextMate has a /path/‍to/‍TextMate.app/‍Contents/‍Resources/‍KeyBindings.dict file with some extra key bindings which are specific to TextMate (and thus not appropriate to put in the per user global key bindings file). You can copy this file to ~/Library/‍Application Support/‍TextMate and edit it, this will then take precedence over the bundled file.

I edited the file and took out the line with nextCompletion, assigned to shift+Esc ($\033) and assigned both Esc and shift+Esc to call noop

```
"\033"     = "noop:";
"$\033"    = "noop:";
```

I learned about the existence of the noop selector here:

- https://github.com/textmate/textmate/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=noop

After quitting and relaunching TextMate Esc now does nothing except close dialogs.

(Apparently to change this one setting, you need to know Objective-C to recognize selector strings, (and assembly which has 'nop') so you can guess that there should be a noop selector. And you need to know octal, so you recognize the Escape key as 033 = 27.)

---

## Things I tried that failed

EDIT: for reference for people wondering how it can take 90 minutes to change one little setting.

I found this paragraph [in the manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text), at the end of section 4.2:

> When you provide your own completion command (or list) you may want to
>   disable the default matches. This can be done by setting
>   disableDefaultCompletion to 1.

I tried setting disableDefaultCompletion to 1 in the Preferences > Variables pane and quitting and reopening the app. I found that Bundle menu > Select Bundle Item and clicking Settings shows a list of all the settings, including my disableDefaultCompletion = 1 at the bottom. Apparently this doesn't do anything? (Other settings overridden by different bundles show as crossed out, which my settings is not.)

I also searched the http://github.com/textmate/textmate repo for the string disableDefaultCompletion and it shows in the search results, so this is feature should exist there somewhere.

I tried quitting the app and then on the commandline:

> defaults write com.macromates.TextMate disableDefaultCompletion true

Relaunching and trying again (hitting Esc to the right of a close } in JavaScript mode) and it is still not disabling completion.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I hate that feature also, but I lived with it for months, and now I finally gave up and tried to fix it but failed to do so. Luckly I found your post. I would just add that for me I didnt have the \033 line on the file, I had to add it to (I only had the $\033 line which I replaced the contents to noop).

Comment: Dear god, i just stumbled upon this. Are they serious? Why not make the escape key insert random words in a text editor? Sounds like fun... Thanks for pointing out a solution, although the non-existance of a simple settings flag for this might cause me to look for another text editor...

Comment: Total awesomeness!

Comment: Thanks again, a few years later I found this again. Anyway, wanted to point out that it seems that after each update to TextMate you lose that config and have to re-do it (and if you're like me, you will forget you had this problem and have to re-search it after months suffering with it again). What does TextMate team have in mind to add such a weird behavior to a safe key?

Comment: Another year and I found this same solution again. I have to remember NOT UPDATING TextMate. But of course I will forget and update it again in a few months. See you (myself) again next year.

Comment: Yep, it's me again. Luckily StackOverflow still exists and I found the solution again and it still works. I hate this feature so much, it makes no sense to replace the selected text with random garbage when I press ESC, I dont know why the developer thought this was a good idea.